# Sending a message to someone's Twitter account without following them?

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message

Is it possible to send a private message to another Twitter user without having first followed them?

Or can I send a public message directed at an account without being a follower?

Answer (score 7):

You can send them a public message by posting something with their `@username` in it. Everyone can read it.

There are [private messages](http://support.twitter.com/entries/14606-what-is-a-direct-message-dm), but you can send those only to people who follow you.

> If someone is following you, you can send a direct message from the web via the "message" link on the profile page. Please note: you cannot send a direct message to a user who is not following you.

Answer (score 1):

Some people have their email, phone, address etc... on their twitter page. You could contact them via that.

For a public message to `@twitter`, you could just tweet `@twitter: hey, I'm liking this twitter thing!`

Answer (score 1):

Ask someone who is following him to make a Direct Message (DM).  It would be private between the three of you.

Comment: How do you send that 3rd person private msg though?